# Send full response back along with modified key-value pairs to other API after getting data from one API

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting this as the response from an internal API of my company:

Sample:

```
{
"name":"kolich",
"platform":"web",
"usertype":"paid",
"age":22,
"gender":"male",
"activityStatus":"active",
"isNewUser":false

}
```

I'm modifying the values of these keys and just sending them to the update api using post request

payload:

```
{
"activityStatus":"inactive",
"isNewUser":true

}
```

Problem :

When I am sending only those updated values to the API, all other values of other keys except name are becoming empty. How can I send updated key values along with the non updated key value pairs?

I'm using Google sheets and apps script do the above operations.

How can I send full response back to the API along with modified key value pairs? Sample only has 7 fields but I actually have 31 fields.
How can I achieve it?

P.S - I cannot make any changes to the API code.

Comment: I don't know what restrictions google sheets imposes on your code, but in modern JS, you can just send back `{...response, activityStatus: "inactive", isNewUser:true}`

Comment: But in this case wont those two keys be repeated? Also, how can I send payload like you've mentioned because response would be like this {{
"name":"kolich",
"platform":"web",
"usertype":"paid",
"age":22,
"gender":"male",
"activityStatus":"active",
"isNewUser":false

}}, modified key:values}. This would give a error because of incorrect format

Comment: You might want to investigate the [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

Comment: It is not working in Google apps script? I tried with the above mentioned syntax

Comment: I'm not terribly surprised.  Well, you'll have to do it another way.  The answer from Sergey may work.  I'm not a big fan of mutating data received but if the whole idea is to update the server, it might not be so bad.

Comment: Can you please share any example of what Sergey has answered? Would be a great help

Comment: Sergey's answer is simple and clear.  I have no idea how one would elaborate it.

Comment: Your solution worked. Can you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward with the [Object Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals).  You should just be able to send back:

```js
{...response, activityStatus: "inactive", isNewUser:true}
```

But as Sergey points out, you could also mutate the object you get, if you have no further use for it or if you need to use it with those changes applied:

```js
const process = async (...args) => {
  // do some work
  const response = await getTheData()
  // do some more work

  response.activityStatus = 'inactive';
  response.isNewUser = true

  // do even more work
  const acknowledgement = await updateTheServer(response)
  // you get the idea 
}
```

While I personally prefer to avoid mutating input objects, the choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your response to an object and mutate it like so:

```
res.activityStatus = "inactive"
res.isNewUser = true
```

Then send the object back.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but can you please elaborate it?